# Should logging out bring you to a login page?

Tags: usability, website-design, navigation, login

When a user clicks logout it logs them out then redirects them to the login page. My question is should I do this or should I bring them back to the page they logged out from?

Comment: It should take them to the Home page of the site (which presumably you do not need to be logged in to view, but if so, then the login page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test your users, or review other sites, especially your competitors and see what they do.

Make a spreadsheet and examine your results. If everyone: on-line merchants,banks, and other sites all do the same thing - then that would be a good choice as it would be the industry standard.

The two choices I see most often (correct me if I'm wrong) are:

1. Return to home page
2. Stay on the current page (the page they logged out from)

I don't recall many sites sending one to the login page. (Assuming there is a separate and distinct login page).

Regardless, the more this concerns you the more you should examine industry standards and be able to present your findings to the team.

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

If what you are logged into is blocked from those not signed in, then you should take them to a login page or form overlay. If people can still view the content, such as this page, then you should just log them out with some indication that this has taken place.

Answer (score 0):

It should inform the user they were logged out successfully and provide a way to easily log back in. This could be a link back to the login form or the login form can be present. The login prices should be within two clicks.